# LINQ null reference exception on join

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm getting a null reference exception for the following linq query:

```
 Dim Report = From Filter In EDTKPDPDescVar _
                         Group Join EDTK In eDTKBase _
                         On Filter.eDTK_PDP_Code Equals EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Code _
                         Into g = Group _
                         From EDTK In g.DefaultIfEmpty _
                         Group Join PLI In ProdBase _
                         On EDTK.eDTK_PLI Equals PLI.Siebel_PLI _
                         Into h = Group _
                         From PLI In h.DefaultIfEmpty _
                         Select eDTK_PDP_Code = Filter.eDTK_PDP_Code, _
                                eDTK_PLI = EDTK.eDTK_PLI, _
                                System = "eDTK Instance: " + EDTK.eDTK_Instance, _
                                PDD_PDP_Description = EDTK.PDD_PDP_Description, _
                                Siebel_PDP_Description = PLI.Siebel_PDP_Description, _
                                eDTK_PDP_Description = EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Description
```

The field (data type is string) that is creating the error is this one:

```
 Siebel_PDP_Description = PLI.Siebel_PDP_Description
```

How can I prevent this error from popping up without an if/then statement testing for null and assigning a value?

Comment: Well, what is the behaviour that you expect? If you don't want nulls in this result set, don't use left join (you are explicitly doing `DefaultIfEmpty`).

Comment: I do want the nulls in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're essentially doing a left join (by using `DefaultIfEmpty`), some instances of `PLI` from `h.DefaultIfEmpty` might be null.  So, in the `Select` clause, you cannot try to read a property off of `PLI` by calling `PLI.Siebel_PDP_Description`, since it may be null.  Try using a small `If` statement in the instantiation of new object:

```
Select Siebel_PDP_Description = If(PLI Is Nothing, Nothing, PLI.Siebel_PDP_Description)
```